# js-hotkeys, function raised twice when combination is more than 1 key

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using [js-hotkeys](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/wiki/about). I have a problem where when my key combination is more than 1 key, eg. "Shift+Tab", my function is raised twice.

```
$("textarea").bind("keydown", "shift+tab", function() { ... });
```

See what happens here -> http://jsbin.com/osuza5/2/edit. seems like with 1 key it also triggers twice there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has happened since jQuery 1.4.2, [it's a known issue](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/issues/detail?id=78).  Luckily, John Resig forked this and created a *much* cleaner version a while back that also ...well - it works, [you can check it out here](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/).

Updating your jsbin to point at this plugin version: https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/raw/master/jquery.hotkeys.js (and that's the *only* change), it works.  [You can test it out here](http://jsbin.com/osuza5/3).

Answer (score 0):

Try Code:

$("textarea").bind("keydown", "shift+tab", function(e) 
{ e.preventDefault;  bla..bla... });

Link: http://jsbin.com/osuza5/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

Notice the combinations mentioned twice during binding. One along with the "keydown.shift+tab". 
To keep it from firing multiple times in some browsers, unbind the hotkey in the end of the function. This worked for me. 
I've used the original version from http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/

Please note that using this will probably keep you from overriding any of the browser defaults. Hence, even though things will go as expected, but as soon as the unbinding occurs, the browser may switch tabs (shift+tab) because of this .

```
$("textarea").bind("keydown.shift+tab", "shift+tab", function() { ... 
//Your Code Here

//this should be in the end
$("textarea").unbind("keydown.shift+tab", "shift+tab");
});
```